# Struggling with react-native build

Tags: react-native, gradle, deployment, build, expo

I am about to finish my first app but there is an issue I'm afraid I can't resolve by myself. While the build process for android app the builder returns the following error which I dont have a clue how to fix. Any help will be much appreciated!

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 1 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.

BUILD FAILED in 2m 14s

Comment: What command are you running for build?

Comment: I use expo and the build command is "eas bulid" which gave the reported error above. However I found a workaround solution by making a local build with ./gradlew build which passes successfuly and it generates the debug and release apk which are running for now.